# How to extract number from string?

Tags: r, stringr

I have

```
strQuestions <- c("Q1", "Q22")
```

I need to get

```
nQuestions <- c(1,22)
```

How can I do it nicely? (with stringr?). Thank you

Comment: @akrun those two posts have pretty different aims: one is about truncating strings, the other is about substituting commonly accepted English abbreviation standards. Neither are relevant on this post.

Comment: @akrun Not my downvote but two hits under the top10 when I google for OP's question title make it a dupe for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `stringr`:

```
str_sub(strQuestions, 2, 3)
stringr::str_remove_all(strQuestions,"[A-Za-z]")
```

You can add the function `as.numeric()` after.